# Korn Shell: End, pgup, pgdown, and delete key not working

Tags: shell, freebsd, keyboard, emacs, ksh

So basically my <kbd>End</kbd>, <kbd>Pageup</kbd>/<kbd>Pagedown</kbd>, and <kbd>Delete</kbd> key are not working in ksh93. I'm running FreeBSD by the way.

My arrow keys are working, and so is my home key.

Those keys work when I put this in my `.kshrc`

```
set -o emacs
```

I have tried doing [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1623256/make-arrow-and-delete-keys-work-in-korn-shell-command-line), by putting this in my `.kshrc`. To make the <kbd>End</kbd> key work.

```
alias __Y=`echo "\005"`     # end = ^e = end of line
```

I opened up vim, and pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>v</kbd>, and typed <kbd>0</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>5</kbd>. And the `^E` showed up. Still, nothing worked.

Anyone know anyway to get those key to work?

Also, When ever I press those keys it prints out a `~`. I also know that I could use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>d</kbd>, or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>a</kbd>, I do NOT want to use these.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[That answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2539905) is specific to certain terminal emulators, I don't think it can be generalized outside Solaris.

In ksh, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> then <kbd>End</kbd>. This will insert a literal escape character followed by the rest of the escape sequence that the key sends. For example, you might see `^[[4~` (the `^[` at the beginning is in fact an escape character, not `^` followed by `[`). Do the same for the other cursor keys you want to reconfigure.

In your `.kshrc`, set a [KEYBD trap](http://www2.research.att.com/sw/download/man/man1/ksh.html#Key%20Bindings) to translate the escape sequences from the function keys into the bindings for the commands you want the key to invoke. For example (you may need to adjust the escape sequences — note that inside `$'…',`\e` means an escape character):

```
keybd_trap () {
  case ${.sh.edchar} in
    $'\e[1~') .sh.edchar=$'\001';; # Home = beginning-of-line
    $'\e[4~') .sh.edchar=$'\005';; # End = end-of-line
    $'\e[5~') .sh.edchar=$'\e>';; # PgUp = history-previous
    $'\e[6~') .sh.edchar=$'\e<';; # PgDn = history-next
    $'\e[3~') .sh.edchar=$'\004';; # Delete = delete-char
  esac
}
trap keybd_trap KEYBD
set -o emacs
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. But now I'm getting an error that says .kshrc: line 6: syntax error: ')' unexpected

Comment: Right where the keybd_trap () { part is.

Comment: @shix Sorry, there was a typo (an extra parenthesis on each case line), fixed now.

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much. I've had this problem for a while now.